# How to use an "otherwise" clause in `Which`

Tags: conditional, code-review

I want to classify a set of vectors according to the number and position of zeroes they contain. The components of the vectors are non-negative. I'm using

```
step = 1/3;
grid = Flatten[
 Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[1, {3}, Range[0, 1, step]], 1];
listas =
 Split[
  Sort[
   Table[{
    Which[
     grid[[i, 1]] == 0, 1, 
     grid[[i, 2]] == 0, 2, 
     grid[[i, 3]] == 0, 3, 
     grid[[i, 1]] > 0, 0], grid[[i]]
     },
   {i,1, Length[grid]}],
   #1[[1]] < #2[[1]] &
  ], 
  First[#1] === First[#2] &]
```

which works but feels clumsy. In particular, I'm not very happy with the last clause in `Which`, that was meant as an "otherwise." I understand that this results in the mis-classification of vectors with several zeros, (they appear as either "1" or "2") this is not a major concern for me, as there are only three such cases.

Comment: If you click on the orange "Details" in the documentation for `Which` it mentions that you can use `True` for your final test and that should act as your "otherwise."

Comment: `lista = {Count[#, 0], #} & /@ grid` This avoids an extra level of `List` brackets that your approach includes.

Comment: @Bill Anyone else define `Else = True` for this purpose?

Comment: @BobHanlon, I believe this doesn't record the zeroes position (just their number). I see now that the wording of my question is inaccurate, since I definitely wnat to know where the zeroes are and I care much less about how many of them are

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
listas = GroupBy[grid, FirstPosition[#, 0] &]
```

It gives a slightly different structure, but is semantically equivalent.

Comment: I guess I should comment that this, I think, solves your problem of classifying vectors, but it does not answer the question about "otherwise" in Which expressions. You can just use True as the final Which condition.